# React Native WebView not load source

Tags: react-native, android-webview

#### Description

I want to use React Native WebView  for "Integration With Existing Android Apps", but it not load source. And it not invoke WebView's `onLoad`, `onLoadStart`, `onError`.

#### Reproduction Steps and Sample Code

```
render() {
  let { url, headers, html } = this.props;

  if (!!url && !/^[a-zA-Z-_]+:/.test(url)) 
  {
    url = 'http://' + url;
  }

  if (html) 
  {
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>'+html+'</body></html>'
  }

  console.log(html);
  const source = !!url ? {uri: url} : {html: html}

  console.log(source);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          source={source}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          decelerationRate="normal"
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          startInLoadingState={!!url}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          renderError={()=>{
            return (
              <View></View>
            )
          }}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I found two, but they not solve my question:

- [React Native Webview not loading any url (React native web view not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451139/react-native-webview-not-loading-any-url-react-native-web-view-not-working)
- [React Native WebView is not loading the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454820/react-native-webview-is-not-loading-the-source)

#### #

React Native Version: 0.37.0
Android Studio Version: 2.2.2

Comment: I think the problem is your network. Test a simple webView:

`<WebView source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}} />`

Comment: It is not the network problem.Thank you all the same.

Comment: public class AndroidImage extends SimpleViewManager<ImageView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "UcaImageView";
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

Answer (score 0):

We found a error in our code:
This custrom view's class name cover React Native class name

```
public class CustomImageView extends SimpleViewManager<ImageView> {
  // Error: This class name: RCTWebView cover React Native class name
  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTWebView";
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
 }
}
```